# Having Trouble with PHP Word Guessing Game

Tags: php, arrays

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $guess = $_POST['guess'];
        $count = isset($_POST['count']) ? $_POST['count']:0;
        $count++;
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Guess the Word Game</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id = "header">
</div>

<div id = "word">
<?php

//create array
$words = array("aardvarks", "determine", "different", "greatness", "miserable");

$random = array_rand($words);
//choose a random word from array
$newWord = $words[$random];

$change = str_split($newWord);
//prints out array
/*foreach($change as $list) {
    echo $list;
}*/
$masked = str_replace($change, '*', $change);
//prints masked array
foreach($masked as $hide) {
echo $hide;
}

?>
</div>

<div id = "guess">

<form name="guessLetter" method="POST" action=""
<p>Please input your guess below</p>
<input type="text" name="guess" id="guess"/><br />

<input type="hidden" name="count" id="count" value="<?php echo $count; ?>" />

<?php

?>

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    echo "Guess: ".$guess."<br />";
    echo "Count: ".$count;
}

?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Hi everyone

I am relatively new to PHP and in the process of creating a word guessing game.

I have created an array of words and then randomized them. Once a word has been chosen, I have split the word into an array. I have then created another array for the masked version of the word which appears on the screen.

I have been ok up to here, but I now need to use a loop to iterate through array to see if the letter guessed is actually in the word. I also want to tell the user how many times the letter appears and also update the masked version of the word, with the actual letter.

I have included my code so far and would really appreciate some help as I am stuck!!

Comment: your `$count` is not initialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I now need to use a loop to iterate through array to see if the letter guessed is actually in the word

```
$letter_is_in_word = stristr($selected_word, $guess);
// returns either false if not found, or a section of the string 
// where it was found ($letter_is_in_word == true)
```

> I also want to tell the user how many times the letter appears

```
$number_of_occurences = substr_count($selected_word, $guess);
```

> ... and also update the masked version of the word, with the actual letter.

```
// get your random word
$random = array_rand($words);
$selected_word = $words[$random];

// set up temporary array to store output letters or *
$output = array();
// split word into each letter
$letters = str_split($selected_word);

foreach($letters as $letter) {
    // if the letter was guessed correctly, add it to the output array, 
    // otherwise add a *
    $output[] = ($letter == $guess) ? $letter : '*';
}

// output the results (implode joins array values together)
echo implode($output);
```

---

Something to note here is that while you are tracking the guess count via hidden input field, you aren't tracking previous guesses. I would suggest you use a hidden input field to store previous guesses also.

At the top of your page:

```
$count = 0;
$guesses = array();
if(isset($_POST['guesses']))
    $guesses = explode('|', $_POST['guesses']);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $guess = trim(strtolower($_POST['guess']));
    if(!in_array($guess, $guesses))
        $guesses[] = $guess;

    $count = isset($_POST['count']) ? (int) $_POST['count'] : 0;
    $count++;
}
```

Then further down:

```
<input type="hidden" name="guesses" id="guesses" value="<?=implode('|', $guesses)?>">
```

This allows you to track previous guesses (hidden field in this example is delimited by `|` characters). You'll then need to check that array when you decide which letters to * out:

```
foreach($letters as $letter) {
    // if the current letter has already been guessed, add it to 
    // the output array, otherwise add a *
    $output[] = in_array($letter, $guesses) ? $letter : '*';
}
```